# FindControl can't find a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I have a problem with FindControl function. The problem is as follow:

aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <table class="inputTable">
            <tr><td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Extern" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChangedMethod" runat="server" />
                </td><td>Externes Unternehmen</td></tr>
    <tr>         
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Firmierung" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="Firmierung" Display="Dynamic" 
                ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
                Text="Bitte geben Sie die Firmierung ein."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void OnCheckedChangedMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (Extern.Checked)
        {                
            Control ctr = FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator1");                
            if (ctr != null)
            {
                ctr.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {                
        }
    }
```

But FindControl didn't work, it couldn't find that control. Was I wrong at any point?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; since you have runat="server" on your RequiredFieldValidator, why can't you just reference it directly in the code-behind?

Comment: @ Jim B: yeah, you're right, I just forgot that. Now it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your limited source, you should be able to simplify your code behind method to:

```
protected void OnCheckedChangedMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.RequiredFieldValidator1.Visible = this.Extern.Checked;
}
```

There should be no need for the use of FindControl().

When you type "this.", if you don't see RequiredFieldValidator1 appear in your intellisense, and assuming you are using ASP.NET 2.0 or greater, check your VS.NET warnings to see if your .aspx has a warning message with an associated "Generation of designer file failed". If so, you must correct the warning.

Comment: Thanks Shan, I just forgot that I can call it directly as a reference. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET creates a field for you, as it is located inside a `Content`: `this.RequiredFieldValidator1` in your page.

The `FindControl` way would be like this (find it in the master page's content panel):

```
Control ctr = Master.FindControl("MainContent")
    .FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator1");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Mudu, now it works with Master. but I go with the solution of Shan below, it's simple. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah, I'd recommend you so too, Shan's solution is safer.

Comment: Thank you, man. I wonder why no one doesn't consider the usage of Master Page while explaining how to use from FindContro(). Thank you again.